# Validate Regex groups with OR when both groups are present in Java code

Tags: java, regex, validation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Need to validate a format where either of transport and protocol can be present or both can be. I have applied this regex to validate both the group. But when any one validation succeeds, it does not validate other group, like in the code.
Note: transport can accepts either tcp, sctp or udp and protocol can either accept radius, diameter and tacacs+.

Like example, if both transport and protocol are part of URL, and if format of transport is correct and it validates with the value provided in Regex, then it returns true even if the value of protocol is invalid.

Java Code:

```
String pattern = "((?=.*;transport=(tcp|sctp|udp)\\b)|(?=.*;protocol=(diameter|radius|tacacs+)\\b))";
String url = "transport=tcp;protocol=aradius";
    Pattern regExPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    if(regExPattern.matcher(url).find()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

This returns true, since it validates transport successfully but unable to validate protocol values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what strings shall be detected as valid, but let me try to give an example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{

    private static void check(String s,Pattern regExPattern)
    {
        boolean matches=regExPattern.matcher(s).matches();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("matches:"+regExPattern.matcher(s).matches()+", find:"+regExPattern.matcher(s).find());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String pattern = "((.+=.+;transport=(tcp|sctp|udp))||(.+=.+;protocol=(diameter|radius|tacacs\\+)))";
        Pattern regExPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        check("transport=tcp;protocol=diameter", regExPattern);
        check("transport=udp", regExPattern);
        check("protocol=radius", regExPattern);
        check("other=other;protocol=radius", regExPattern);
        check("other=other;transport=sctp", regExPattern);
        check("wrong;protocol=tacacs+", regExPattern);
        check("wrong;transport=tcp", regExPattern);
        check("wrong;wrong", regExPattern);
        check("something else;transport=tcp;protocol=diameter;something else", regExPattern);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
transport=tcp;protocol=diameter
matches:true, find:true

transport=udp
matches:false, find:true

protocol=radius
matches:false, find:true

other=other;protocol=radius
matches:true, find:true

other=other;transport=sctp
matches:true, find:true

wrong;protocol=tacacs+
matches:false, find:true

wrong;transport=tcps
matches:false, find:true

wrong;wrong
matches:false, find:true

something else;transport=tcp;protocol=diameter;something else
matches:false, find:true
```

I replaced `?` by `.+` because `?` matches only a single character, `.+` matches more than one characters. Then you can use `match()` instead of `find()`.

match() requires that the whole string matches the pattern. find() requires that only part of the string matches a part of the pattern. I think you wanted to match (not find).

I replaced `.*` by `.+` because `.*` matches any number of characters (including zero) but I assume that you only want to match at least one character here.

I removed the `\\b` because that matches the character `b` literally which seems to be not what you want.

I replaced `tacacs+` by `tacacs\\+` because you wanted to match the `+` literally not matching all all words that start with `tacacs` and any number of `s` like `tacacsssssss`.

The website https://regex101.com/ is very helpful to test regular expression because it marks parts of the pattern with colors and explains what the parts mean.

Instead of using complex expressions that you do not understand you might check the two parts individually and then write an `if (matches || matches2)...` statement that checks if at least one of both match:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{

    private static void check(String s, String pattern1, String pattern2)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
        boolean matches1 = s.matches(pattern1);
        boolean matches2 = s.matches(pattern2);
        if (matches1 || matches2)
        {
            System.out.println("matches");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("does not match");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String pattern1 = ".*;transport=(tcp|sctp|udp).*";
        String pattern2 = ".*;protocol=(diameter|radius|tacacs\\+).*";

        check("transport=tcp;protocol=diameter", pattern1, pattern2);
        check("transport=udp", pattern1, pattern2);
        check("protocol=radius", pattern1, pattern2);
        check("other=other;protocol=radius", pattern1, pattern2);
        check("other=other;transport=sctp", pattern1, pattern2);
        check("wrong;protocol=tacacs+", pattern1, pattern2);
        check("wrong;transport=tcp", pattern1, pattern2);
        check("wrong;wrong", pattern1, pattern2);
        check("something else;transport=tcp;protocol=diameter;something else", pattern1, pattern2);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
transport=tcp;protocol=diameter
matches
transport=udp
does not match
protocol=radius
does not match
other=other;protocol=radius
matches
other=other;transport=sctp
matches
wrong;protocol=tacacs+
matches
wrong;transport=tcp
matches
wrong;wrong
does not match
something else;transport=tcp;protocol=diameter;something else
matches
```

Answer (score 0):

The complication is that the transport and protocol are both optional and appear in any order. To do this in *one* regex I have an alternation using `|` where in the first alternative the transport parameter is scanned first and the protocol parameter is optional and in the second alternative things are reversed. To implement an optional regular expression `A` that can appear far into the input stream, my approach is to use:

`(.*(?<tag>A)|)` If regular expression `A` appears in the input stream, scan for A, else scan no characters. But either way there is a match.

You cannot use:

`.*(?<tag>A)?` because the regex engine satisfies this trivially by scanning 0 characters and never scanning `A`.

The regex:

```
;transport=(?<transport1>tcp|sctp|udp)\b(.*;protocol=(?<protocol1>diameter|radius|tacacs+)\b|)|;protocol=(?<protocol2>diameter|radius|tacacs+)\b(.*;transport=(?<transport2>tcp|sctp|udp)\b|)
```

[See regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VsFZqP/2/)

The program:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String tests[] = {
            "aaa;transport=tcp  ;protocol=radius",
            "aaa;protocol=diameter    ;transport=udp",
            "aaa;transport=sctp",
            "aaa;protocol=tacacs",
            "aaaa"
        };
        for (String test: tests) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(";transport=(?<transport1>tcp|sctp|udp)\\b(.*;protocol=(?<protocol1>diameter|radius|tacacs+)\\b|)|;protocol=(?<protocol2>diameter|radius|tacacs+)\\b(.*;transport=(?<transport2>tcp|sctp|udp)\\b|)");
            System.out.println(test);
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(test);
            if (m.find()) {
                String protocol = m.group("protocol1") == null ? m.group("protocol2") :  m.group("protocol1");
                String transport = m.group("transport1") == null ? m.group("transport2") : m.group("transport1");
                if (protocol != null) {
                    System.out.println("   protocol=" + protocol);
                }
                if (transport != null) {
                    System.out.println("   transport=" + transport);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
aaa;transport=tcp  ;protocol=radius
   protocol=radius
   transport=tcp
aaa;protocol=diameter    ;transport=udp
   protocol=diameter
   transport=udp
aaa;transport=sctp
   transport=sctp
aaa;protocol=tacacs
   protocol=tacacs
aaaa
```

**Note**

It would be simpler to use two separate regular expressions and two calls to `find` to scan the transport and protocol values. At least the regular expressions would be far simpler.